# Flash CS5 AS3 - runtime error with text box

Tags: actionscript-3, text, runtime-error, tlf

I get the following runtime error due to my text box:

```
Error: SymbolClassLoader can't find Resource with id = 2, name = 'Cube_Inventory_HUD__LoadingAnimation__'
Error: SymbolClassLoader can't find Resource with id = 3, name = 'Cube_Inventory_HUD__Content__'
Warning: The method Loader::loadBytes() is not implemented
```

None of my sprites/symbols appear because of this error, just a blank white stage when I run. 

When I delete the textbox and run, everything runs fine and all my sprites/symbols appear as expected.

Additional information: 

The name of my .fla and .as files is Cube_Inventory_HUD. 

Note that I'm compiling/running the .swf in Scaleform Launcher's FxMediaPlayer as I'm making some scaleform UI for UDK. 

The text box I'm using is TLF Text, Editable (because I intend to change the text at runtime later using ActionScript). The font is Arial, Bold. 

The actionscript code in the .as file is just the default one; I haven't typed in anything extra yet.

Comment: With this amount of information it's impossible to advice you. It's looks like there is a lot of moving parts in behind. Provide the key parts of your source code and tell what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Scaleform doesn't support TLF text yet. At least it hasn't ever worked for me. Try making the text box using classic text.

Answer (score 0):

TLF textfields are not currently supported in Scaleform. Instead, use Classic Text.